# Typescript compiler includes typings of outDir

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm having an issue when typescript compiler tries to include `*.d.ts` files from library output folder and then build fails as it can't rewrite those files. Apparently files are included because of following configuration in `package.json`:

```
"main": "lib/index.js",
"typings": "lib/index.d.ts",
```

In `tsconfig.json` I have set up output folder and bunch of other configurations that are probably irrelevant in this case.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib"
},
```

And the problem itself is when I run `tsc --listFiles` I can see that files from output folder are included:

```
...
<project-root>/lib/contracts/index.d.ts
<project-root>/lib/profiler/profile-request.d.ts
<project-root>/lib/profiler/profile-response.d.ts
<project-root>/lib/profiler/index.d.ts
<project-root>/lib/config/elastic.config.d.ts
...
```

And that later results in error:

```
error TS5055: Cannot write file '<project-root>lib/config/app.config.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
...
```

Is this expected behavior for typescript compiler to include files in this 
scenario?

And should I just remove `main / typings` configuration from `package.json`? It is advised to have that configuration in doc [Publishing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-a-file-in-the-exclude-list-still-picked-up-by-the-compiler